# Error TS1005: '>' expected. node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/engine/training_utils.d.ts

Tags: angular, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to get tensorflow.js working within my existing angular project. Once I start compiling my project with ng serve I get the following error:

> ERROR in
>   node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/engine/training_utils.d.ts(71,92):
>   error TS1005: '>' expected.
>   node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-layers/dist/engine/training_utils.d.ts(71,129):
>   error TS1109: Expression expected.

I have the following local versions in my project:

- "@tensorflow/tfjs": "^1.2.8"
- local Angular CLI version 1.7.4
- "typescript": "^2.6.2"

Comment: How did you install tensorflow/tfjs, I mean which command line did you use for npm install ?

Comment: Yes, used npm install. But I just fixed the error myself by simply updating my typescript version to 3.3.3333

Answer (score 1):

By checking the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/setup), you can find the following statement:

> When using TypeScript you may need to set `skipLibCheck: true` in your
>   `tsconfig.json` file if your project makes use of strict null checking
>   or you will run into errors during compilation.

So, you should set the following setting on the tsconfig.json:

```
"skipLibCheck": true
```

If the error persists, try to update your typescript version to 3+;